# React Native iOS - I get addNetworkingHandler and NetInfo invariant violation errors after installing Firebase pods. How do I fix them?

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, podfile

After adding the podfile and installing Firebase I get this errors:

> addNetworkingHandler on target BlobMdule with params()

> requiring module "node_modules/react-native/libraries/network/netinfo.js"

which threw an exception:

> invariant violation: Native module cannot be null.

I have tried everything but no luck. If you know about these errors please help! Screenshots:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MhG5.png]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your podfile:

```
`pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'RCTText',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket'
]`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i was able to fix the issue. All I did was to link RCTNetwork manually.